# Python - Problem with extract data from json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, instagram-api

To extract data on Instagram entries, I need to download the media list and then download the data separately for each entry.
I'm just doing something wrong because it only gets me data for 1 entry and not for everyone that I have to change to get it correctly.

This is the code at the moment:

```
import urllib.request as o
import json
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1234567891011/media?fields=media_type,like_count,comments_count,timestamp&limit=500&access_token=xxx'
link1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/'
link2 = '/insights?metric=engagement%2Cimpressions%2Creach%2Csaved&access_token=xxx'
with o.urlopen(url) as jfile :
    data1 = json.load(jfile)
    df = json_normalize(data1["data"])
    linki = []
    for dane3 in df:
        linki = link1 + df['id'] + link2
        dx = []
        with o.urlopen(linki[0]) as file2 :
            data2 = json.load(file2)
            dx = json_normalize(data2["data"],
                              record_path ='values',
                              meta =['id', 'name', 'title'])
            dx['ident'] =dx['id'][0].split("/")[0]
dn7 = dx.pivot(index='ident', columns='name', values='value')
dn7
```

The data I want to extract is:

```
ident|engagement|impressions|reach|saved
987654321|65|2142|1943|2
```

What do I need to improve in the code I'm using Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration of `for dane3 in df`, you are re-assigning `dx` according to the current json response `DataFrame`. This means that you are only keeping the information related to the last post processed.

Instead, you could keep a list of the normalized JSON `DataFrame`s and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)enate them once all of the posts have been processed.

You are also using the same post ID on every iteration of the `for` loop, via `df['id']` and `linki[0]`, which means that you will only get the data for the first post. Instead, your loop should iterate over the values of the `'id'` column of your `DataFrame`, i.e. `for post_id in df['id']`.

```
post_data = []
with o.urlopen(url) as jfile:
    data1 = json.load(jfile)
    df = json_normalize(data1["data"])
    for post_id in df['id']:
        linki = link1 + post_id + link2
        with o.urlopen(linki) as file2:
            data2 = json.load(file2)
            dx = json_normalize(data2["data"],
                                record_path ='values',
                                meta =['id', 'name', 'title'])
            dx['ident'] = dx['id'][0].split("/")[0]
            post_data.append(dx)
dn7 = pd.concat(post_data).pivot(index='ident', columns='name', values='value')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, but probably not quite because in the loop close the same result all the time

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? Have you tested this solution? Unfortunately I can't as I don't have an access token.

Comment: So I tested this solution and behaves similar to mine only 5 times shows the same.